# How to send several insert statements using TSQLConnection.Execute

Tags: mysql, delphi, dbexpress

I'm using `TSQLConnection` to connect to a remote MySql DB.

I want to send several `INSERT` statements at one time, instead of sending one by one (this would be painfully slow).

But, when I try to do this, I get an error from the server.

If I send only one statement, like this, it works:

```pascal
mySQLConnection.Execute('insert into table values (1,100)',nil);
```

But, if I send like this:

```pascal
mySQLConnection.Execute('insert into table values (1,100);insert into table values (2,200);insert into table values (3,300)',nil);
```

The server will raise an exception:

> Project xxx.exe raised exception class TDBXError with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ...

Is there any way to make this work? On MySQL Workbench, the same SQL statement with several `INSERT`s will work, but not in Delphi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to `.execute()` can only execute one query. If you want to insert multiple rows, put more than one list of values after `VALUES`.

```
mySQLConnection.execute('insert into table values (1,100), (2,200), (3,300)',nil);
```

Comment: Can this be done specifying column names ? For instance, i only to fill only specific fields, not all like the example above.

Comment: Yes. In fact, I strongly recommend it. It's a bad idea to depend on the order of the columns.

Comment: But how would be the syntax ? Do i need to repeat column names for reach record ?

Comment: Read the documentation. You only specify the column names once, before `values`.

Comment: This is [SQL 101](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html).

Comment: @AmigoJack Should be, some people skip the class :)